# Re-rendering vaporizes std:accounts-ui's <Accounts.ui.LoginForm />?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, meteor-accounts

[Updated title to reflect current research on this bug.]

## How to Fix this Bug?

---

I'm really not sure what is happening here.  When I click on the "DraftJS" contentEditable - the `<Accounts.ui.LoginForm />` instantly disappears.  I haven't the ***foggiest*** idea why.

Demo:
[image: draftjsvaporizingloginformwithinspector]

#### To see the bug in its current state:

Go to: http://draftjsmeteor.autoschematic.com/

#### To duplicate the problem in your own development environment:

1. Clone this repository: https://github.com/JeremyIglehart/DraftJSMeteor
2. Create a `settings-development.json` file *(you can leave it blank)*
3. Run with `npm start`

---

### The main question:

Does anyone know why DraftJS kills the `<Accounts.ui.LoginForm />`?

After looking into this problem for two days now, I suspect the problem is hiding somewhere in how  [`<Accounts.ui.LoginForm />`](https://github.com/studiointeract/accounts-ui) is doing something - perhaps in their STATES API?  I'm really confused here.  Any help would really be appreciated.

#### Problems I've ruled out:

1. It's not a `Session Variable` problem.  DraftJS doesn't use them - in fact, there are no Session Variables being used at all right now as far as I can detect (using [Meteor Toys](http://meteor.toys/)) (Thanks @mattsouth)
2. It is not DraftJS killing the page somehow.  When removing DraftJS from the equation the problem still exists with just the form and reloading React. (Thanks @wursttheke )
3. The problem is not located in [zetoff:accounts-material-ui](https://github.com/Zetoff/accounts-material-ui) - I removed the package and the problem still exists.

It doesn't seem to me this problem has anything to do with Meteor, or React specifically.

#### Where I'm looking now to solve this:

1. something to do with [std:accounts-ui](https://github.com/studiointeract/accounts-ui)
2. I have no idea where else to look.  Based on the gif demo above you can see that the div with the className `accounts-ui` is rendering just fine - after clicking in the DraftJS contentEditable area, however, something inside this component breaks.

#### Issues Tracking this Bug:

I've created three issues to try and track this down:

**Open**

- [std:accounts-ui:Issue #96](https://github.com/studiointeract/accounts-ui/issues/96)
- (I've also mentioned this on the [Meteor Forums](https://forums.meteor.com/t/draftjs-kills-accounts-material-uis-form-dont-know-why/33464))

**Closed**

- [accounts-material-ui:Issue #26](https://github.com/Zetoff/accounts-material-ui/issues/26) (removed package, bug still exists)
- DraftJS's Github [Issue #962](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/issues/962) (removed DraftJS from the equation, bug persists)

Once I find a solution I'll update all of the issues, forums and questions I've posted everywhere.

Comment: This problem is most likely related to how std:accounts-ui manages state.

Comment: I have found a way to "Put this bug in a jar" perhaps - assuming this is actually a bug.  Take a look at this other StackOverflow question where I have produced a way to "hack" around this issue - but, it still doesn't solve why the state is being lost upon a externally forced re-render: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41911509/is-this-a-bug-or-is-this-react-component-behaving-normally

Answer (score 0):

## Put the bug in a "jar"

This doesn't answer the question, but it does at least work around the bug in a semi-acceptable way.

---

## The question remains, is this a bug - or is this the way React components SHOULD behave?

---

Okay, so this is the end of a very long battle trying to understand what I think is some kind of ***strange*** behavior of this react component.

We [found out later](https://forums.meteor.com/t/draftjs-vaporizes-std-accounts-ui-form-a-weird-bug-need-help-from-react-folks/33464/9?u=autoschematic), that any kind of "re-rendering" caused this react component to "lose it's state" of sorts and just break.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Accounts, STATES } from 'meteor/std:accounts-ui';

class MyEditor extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.forceUpdate()}>Rerender</button>
        <Accounts.ui.LoginForm />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default MyEditor;
```

Okay, so re-rendering of any kind is going to cause this component to fail.

I updated the issue on the github, and went to bed having React/Meteor code nightmares (I know you've been there too if you've read this far).

In the morning I woke up to [find this little gift](https://forums.meteor.com/t/draftjs-vaporizes-std-accounts-ui-form-a-weird-bug-need-help-from-react-folks/33464/13?u=autoschematic) from [Sean](https://github.com/arist0tl3).

Basically to break it down.  If you take the `<Accounts.ui.LoginForm />` out of the same component where the DraftJS component is being drawn - it some how "protects" it from getting re-rendered.  Essentially isolating the bug into a corner where it won't effect the application.

Here's the code:

The original "broken" code where `<Accounts.ui.LoginForm />` lives next to the DraftJS `<Editor />`

```
// Imports

class MyEditor extends Component {

// Other component stuff

return (
  <div className="editor-container">
    <h1>DraftJS and Meteor Editor:</h1>
    <IconButton onClick={this._onBoldClick.bind(this)} touch={true} tooltip="Format Bold" tooltipPosition="top-right">
      <FontIcon className="material-icons" style={iconStyles}>format_bold</FontIcon>
    </IconButton>
    <Editor
      editorState={this.state.editorState}
      onChange={this.onChange}
      handleKeyCommand={this.handleKeyCommand.bind(this)}
      />
    <RaisedButton label="Log Editor State to Console" onClick={this.logState.bind(this)} primary={true} style={buttonStyle} />
  </div>

  <Accounts.ui.LoginForm />

  <p>This is a test - do I stay?</p>
)

// Exports
```

Then Sean took the code out and separated it into respective components in a three step process:

**1. Removed `<Accounts.ui.LoginForm />` from `<MyEditor />`**

```
// Imports

class MyEditor extends Component {

// Other component stuff

return (
  <div className="editor-container">
    <h1>DraftJS and Meteor Editor:</h1>
    <IconButton onClick={this._onBoldClick.bind(this)} touch={true} tooltip="Format Bold" tooltipPosition="top-right">
      <FontIcon className="material-icons" style={iconStyles}>format_bold</FontIcon>
    </IconButton>
    <Editor
      editorState={this.state.editorState}
      onChange={this.onChange}
      handleKeyCommand={this.handleKeyCommand.bind(this)}
      />
    <RaisedButton label="Log Editor State to Console" onClick={this.logState.bind(this)} primary={true} style={buttonStyle} />
  </div>
)

// Exports
```

**2. Created a `<LogIn />` component:**

```
// Imports

class LogIn extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="login-container">

        <Accounts.ui.LoginForm />

        <p>This is a test - do I stay?</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

// Exports
```

**3. Then called the two from a parent `<Home />` component:**

```
class Home extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <MyEditor />
        <LogIn />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

But now, I have this question...  Is this actually a bug, or is this `<Accounts.ui.LoginForm />` component behaving properly?

Another way of asking this question might be - is this normal behavior for a react component, or should the be built to handle arbitrary re-rendering without completely breaking down?